# What is Weierstrass' "simple diagram" in the calculus of variations?

Tags: calculus

In *An essay on the psychology of invention in the mathematical field* Hadamard said this about Weierstrass:

> The two German mathematicians whom Poincaré compares are Weierstrass and Riemann. That, as he concludes, Riemann is typically intuitive and Weierstrass typically logical is beyond contestation. But as to the latter, Poincaré says “You may leaf through all his books without finding a figure.” It strikes me that there happens to be there an error of fact. It is true that almost no memoir of Weierstrass implied any figure: there is only one exception; but there is one, and this exception occurs in one of his most masterly and clear-cut works, one giving the most complete impression of perfection:

> I mean **his fundamental method in the calculus of variations. Weierstrass draws a simple diagram** and, after that initial step is taken, everything goes on in the profoundly logical way which is undoubtedly his characteristic, so that, by merely looking at that diagram, anyone sufficiently acquainted with mathematical methods could have rebuilt the whole argument. But of course there was an initial intuition, that of constructing the diagram. This was the more difficult and the more evidently an act of genius because it meant breaking from the general methods...

In a footnote, Hadamard clarified

> Whether Weierstrass himself actually drew the diagram (or simply described it in words) cannot be said because he did not develop his method elsewhere than in bis oral lectures. That method remained unknown for years, except to bis former students.

In [1], I found a few diagrams, but I am unable to tell which one is this miraculous diagram, since I am unfamiliar with the calculus of variations.

[1] Goldstine, H.H. (1980). Weierstrass. In: A History of the Calculus of Variations from the 17th through the 19th Century. Studies in the History of Mathematics and Physical Sciences, vol 5. Springer, New York, NY. https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4613-8106-8_5